# MySQL put a specific row at the top of the result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a basic SQL select query which returns a set of results. I want a specific row which the entry "Fee" to be put at the top of the results, then the rest.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER By Charges = Fee DESC, Charges DESC
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: As explained with example as an answer : `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY FIELD(Charges, 'Fee') DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this :

```
SELECT * from tbl ORDER BY CASE WHEN Charges = 'Fee' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Charges DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have a use a UNION query. ORDER BY doesn't support this kind of thing by default as far as I know.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Charges = 'Fee'
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY Charges DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `ORDER BY` with a `FIELD` attribute, which would then order by those first.

As I don't have your table definitions, I have throw one together here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91376/13

For sake of it disappearing, the script pretty much consists of;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` char(6) not null,
  `Charges` char(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl` (`Name`, `Charges`)
     VALUES ('One', 'Fee'), ('Two', 'Charge'), ('Three', 'Charge'), 
            ('Four', 'Charge'), ('Five', 'Fee'), ('Six', 'Fee'), 
            ('Seven', 'Invoice'), ('Eight', 'Fee'), ('Nine', 'Invoice'), 
            ('Ten', 'Invoice');

    SELECT *
      FROM tbl
  ORDER BY FIELD(`Charges`, 'Charge') DESC
           ;
```

Which returns:

```
id  Name    Charges
2   Two Charge
3   Three   Charge
4   Four    Charge
1   One Fee
9   Nine    Invoice
8   Eight   Fee
7   Seven   Invoice
6   Six Fee
5   Five    Fee
10  Ten Invoice
```

So, to directly answer your question, your query would be;

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM tbl
ORDER BY FIELD(Charges, 'Fee') DESC
```

**edit** : Viewable, sorted by `Charges = Fee` here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91376/15

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER By FIELD(Charges, 'Fee') DESC
```

You can use something like the above. Where `Charges` is the field and `fee` the specific value. That way you can keep it simple.